# Algorithm- Sum of distances between every two nodes of a Binary Search Tree in O(n)?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming

The question is to find out sum of distances between every two nodes of BinarySearchTree given that every parent-child pair is separated by unit distance. It is to be calculated after every insertion.

ex:

```
 ->first node is inserted..

      (root)

   total sum=0;

->left and right node are inserted

      (root)
      /    \
  (left)   (right)

   total sum = distance(root,left)+distance(root,right)+distance(left,right);
             =        1           +         1          +         2
             =     4

and so on.....
```

Solutions I came up with:

1. Brute-force. Steps:

   1. perform a DFS and track all the nodes : `O(n)`.
   2. Select every two nodes and calculate  : `O(nC2)_times_O(log(n))=O(n2log(n))` distance between them using [Lowest Common Ancestor](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lowest-common-ancestor-in-a-binary-search-tree/) Method and add them up.

   Overall Complexity: `-O(n2log(n))`.
2. `O(nlog(n))`. Steps:-

   1. Before insertion perform DFS and track all nodes : `O(n)`.
   2. Calculate distance between the inserted node and : `O(nlog(n))`. the remaining nodes.
   3. Add the existing sum with the sum calculated in step 2

   Overall Complexity: `-O(nlog(n))`.

Now the question is "is there any solution exists of order of `O(n)`??

Comment: Do you mean O(n) for each query (i.e., after each element is inserted?), OR Given a tree, find the sum of the distances in O(n), with no prior knowledge of the tree?

Comment: Also, the first method you propose is O(n^2*log n).

Comment: @jimmy We have prior knowledge of sum before insertion.

Comment: updated the explanation, any question is welcomed.

Comment: Why unaccepted my answer? If there is any problem, you can leave a comment below my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this by traverse the tree two times.

First, we need three array

`int []left` which stored the sum of the distance of the left sub tree.

`int []right` which stored the sum of the distance of the right sub tree.

`int []up` which stored the sum of the distance of the parent tree (without the current sub tree).

So, first traversal, for each node, we calculate the left and the right distance. If the node is a leaf, simply return 0, if not, we can have this formula:

```
int cal(Node node){
    int left = cal(node.left);
    int right = cal(node.right);
    left[node.index] = left;
    right[node.index] = right;
    //Depend on the current node have left or right node, we add 0,1 or 2 to the final result
    int add = (node.left != null && node.right != null)? 2 : node.left != null ? 1 : node.right != null ? 1 : 0;
    return left + right + add;
}
```

Then for the second traversal, we need to add to each node, the total distance from his parent.

```
             1
            / \
           2   3
          / \
         4   5
```

For example, for node 1 (root), the total distance is `left[1] + right[1] + 2`, `up[1] = 0`; (we add 2 as the root has both left and right sub tree, the exact formula for it is:

```
int add = 0; 
if (node.left != null) 
    add++;
if(node.right != null)
    add++;
```

For node 2 , the total distance is `left[2] + right[2] + add + up[1] + right[1] + 1 + addRight`, `up[2] = up[1] + right[1] + addRight`. The reason there is a `1` at the end of the formula is because there is an edge from the current node to his parent, so we need to add `1`. Now, I denote the additional distance for the current node is `add`, additional distance if there is a left subtree in parent node is `addLeft` and similarly `addRight` for right subtree.

For node 3, the total distance is `up[1] + left[1] + 1 + addLeft`, `up[3] = up[1] + left[1] + addLeft`;

For node 4, the total distance is `up[2] + right[2] + 1 + addRight`, `up[4] = up[2] + right[2] + addRight`;

So depend on the current node is a left or right node, we update the `up` accordingly.

The time complexity is **O(n)**

Comment: Why root is `left[1] + right[1] + 2`? In your formula. it is `left + right + 1`.

Comment: @Sayakiss thanks, because the distance from current node to the left is 1 and to the right is 1, so depending on whether the current node has left or right side or not, we need to add 0 or 1 or 2 into final result.

Comment: Node2's dist is `left[2] + right[2] + 2 + up[1] + right[1] + 1`, but what it exactly is? Please Calculate it out.

Comment: @Sayakiss Ha ha, actually I am so lazy to do the detail, will fix it now :)

Comment: Okay...I'm quite sure the correctness of my solution, but your's looks weird for me(I don't understand your solution indeed)....If it's right, it's a new perspective to consider this problem for me...

Comment: @Sayakiss Can you explain your approach? A simple link will be enough :) normally, this is how I handle the tree (two way directions, from bottom to top, children update parent -> then from top to bottom , parent update children ), but new approach will be interesting.

Comment: @Sayakiss can you please explain your approach toward the problem to solve in O(n)??

Comment: @HarshilSukhadia you need me to explain or Sayakiss? his answer is below.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can find the sum distance of the whole tree between every two node by DP in O(n).
Briefly, you should know 3 things:

```
cnt[i] is the node count of the ith-node's sub-tree
dis[i] is the sum distance of every ith-node subtree's node to i-th node
ret[i] is the sum distance of the ith-node subtree between every two node
```

notice that `ret[root]` is answer of the problem, so just calculate `ret[i]` right and the problem will be done...
How to calculate `ret[i]`? Need the help of `cnt[i]` and `dis[i]` and solve it recursively.
The key problem is:

**Given ret[left] ret[right] dis[left] dis[right] cnt[left] cnt[right] to cal ret[node] dis[node] cnt[node].**

```
              (node)
          /             \
    (left-subtree) (right subtree)
      /                   \
...(node x_i) ...   ...(node y_i)...
important:x_i is the any node in left-subtree(not leaf!) 
and y_i is the any node in right-subtree(not leaf either!).
```

`cnt[node]` is easy,just equals `cnt[left] + cnt[right] + 1`

`dis[node]` is not so hard, equals `dis[left] + dis[right] + cnt[left] + cnt[right]`. reason: sigma(x<sub>i</sub>->left) is `dis[left]`, so sigma(x<sub>i</sub>->node) is `dis[left] + cnt[left]`.

`ret[node]` equal three part:

1. x<sub>i</sub> -> x<sub>j</sub> and y<sub>i</sub> -> y<sub>j</sub>, equals `ret[left] + ret[right]`.
2. x<sub>i</sub> -> node and y<sub>i</sub> -> node, equals `dis[node]`.
3. x<sub>i</sub> -> y<sub>j</sub>:

equals sigma(x<sub>i</sub> -> node -> y<sub>j</sub>), fixed x<sub>i</sub>, then we get cnt[left]*distance(x<sub>i</sub>,node) + sigma(node->y<sub>j</sub>), then  cnt[left]*distance(x<sub>i</sub>,node) + sigma(node->left->y<sub>j</sub>),

and it is `cnt[left]*distance(x_i,node) + cnt[left] + dis[left]`.

Sum up x<sub>i</sub>: `cnt[left]*(cnt[right]+dis[right]) + cnt[right]*(cnt[left] + dis[left])`, then it is `2*cnt[left]*cnt[right] + dis[left]*cnt[right] + dis[right]*cnt[left]`.

Sum these three parts and we get `ret[i]`. Do it recursively, we will get `ret[root]`.

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BSTDistance {
    int[] left;
    int[] right;
    int[] cnt;
    int[] ret;
    int[] dis;
    int nNode;
    public BSTDistance(int n) {// n is the number of node
        left = new int[n];
        right = new int[n];
        cnt = new int[n];
        ret = new int[n];
        dis = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(left,-1);
        Arrays.fill(right,-1);
        nNode = n;
    }
    void add(int a, int b)
    {
        if (left[b] == -1)
        {
            left[b] = a;
        }
        else
        {
            right[b] = a;
        }
    }
    int cal()
    {
        _cal(0);//assume root's idx is 0
        return ret[0];
    }
    void _cal(int idx)
    {
        if (left[idx] == -1 && right[idx] == -1)
        {
            cnt[idx] = 1;
            dis[idx] = 0;
            ret[idx] = 0;
        }
        else if (left[idx] != -1  && right[idx] == -1)
        {
            _cal(left[idx]);
            cnt[idx] = cnt[left[idx]] + 1;
            dis[idx] = dis[left[idx]] + cnt[left[idx]];
            ret[idx] = ret[left[idx]] + dis[idx];
        }//left[idx] == -1 and right[idx] != -1 is impossible, guarranted by add(int,int)  
        else 
        {
            _cal(left[idx]);
            _cal(right[idx]);
            cnt[idx] = cnt[left[idx]] + 1 + cnt[right[idx]];
            dis[idx] = dis[left[idx]] + dis[right[idx]] + cnt[left[idx]] + cnt[right[idx]];
            ret[idx] = dis[idx] + ret[left[idx]] + ret[right[idx]] + 2*cnt[left[idx]]*cnt[right[idx]] + dis[left[idx]]*cnt[right[idx]] + dis[right[idx]]*cnt[left[idx]];
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BSTDistance bst1 = new BSTDistance(3);
        bst1.add(1, 0);
        bst1.add(2, 0);
        //   (0)
        //  /   \
        //(1)   (2)
        System.out.println(bst1.cal());
        BSTDistance bst2 = new BSTDistance(5);
        bst2.add(1, 0);
        bst2.add(2, 0);
        bst2.add(3, 1);
        bst2.add(4, 1);
        //       (0)
        //      /   \
        //    (1)   (2)
        //   /   \
        // (3)   (4)
        //0 -> 1:1
        //0 -> 2:1
        //0 -> 3:2
        //0 -> 4:2
        //1 -> 2:2
        //1 -> 3:1
        //1 -> 4:1
        //2 -> 3:3
        //2 -> 4:3
        //3 -> 4:2
        //2*4+3*2+1*4=18
        System.out.println(bst2.cal());
    }
}
```

output:

```
4
18
```

For the convenience(of readers to understand my solution), I paste the value of `cnt[],dis[] and ret[]` after `bst2.cal()` is called:

```
cnt[] 5 3 1 1 1 
dis[] 6 2 0 0 0
ret[] 18 4 0 0 0
```

PS:
It's the solution from [UESTC_elfness](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=MemberProfile&cr=22885862), it's a simple problem for him , and I'm [sayakiss](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=MemberProfile&cr=22881627), the problem is not so hard for me..

So you can trust us...

Answer (score 1):

First, add four variables to every node. The four variables are sum of distance to the left offspring, sum of distance to the right offspring, number of node in left offspring and number of node in right offspring. Denote them as l, r, nl and nr.

Second, add a total variable to root node to record the sum after each insertion.

The idea is if you have total of current Tree, the new total after inserting a new node is (old total + sum of distance of new node to all other nodes). What you need to calculate in every insertion is sum of distance of new node to all other nodes.

```
1- Insert the new node with four variable set to zero.
2- Create two temp counter "node travel" and "subtotal" with value zero.
3- Back trace the route from new node to root. 
   a- go up to parent node
   b- add one to node travel 
   c- add node travel to subtotal
   d- add (nr * node travel) + r to subtotal if the new node is on left offspring
   e- add node travel to l
   f- add one to nl
4- Add subtotal to total
```

1 - O(n)

2 - O(1)

3 - O(log n), a to f take O(1)

4 - O(1)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean O(n) per each insertion, then it can be done, assuming you do it after each and every insertion, starting with the root.

```
0- Record the current sum of the distances. Call it s1: O(1).
1- Insert the new node: O(n).
2- Perform a BFS, starting at this new node.
   For each new node you discover, record its distance to the start (new) node, as BFS always does: O(n).
   This gives you an array of the distances from the start node to all other nodes.
3- Sum these distances up. Call this s2: O(n).
4- New_sum = s1 + s2: O(1).
```

This algorithm is thus O(n).

Comment: can you explain how it is O(n)??? because BFS() takes O(n) and for every node(total n nodes) we have to calculate distance between them and new node which take n.O(h),(h=height) ie n.O(logn)=O(nlog(n)). Right???

Comment: The general BFS algorithm already calculates the shortest distance from the start node to all other nodes in the graph (tree, in this case). As you said, BFS is O(n), and since you can get all distances using BFS, then the whole algorithm is O(n). There are no 'log's anywhere. I did not use LCA. If you're still confused, I suggest you look at [this](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.884/spring10/labs/lab4.pdf) reference on BFS. Check out the pseudocode on page 2 to see how it calculates the distances while iterating over the nodes.